# Python flatten list joined by string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists which I want to flatten while inserting an item in between them.
My original list is in the form:

```
l = [["a","b"],["c"],["d"]]
```

What I want is, to flatten the list and separate them with a character

```
n = ["a","b",".","c",".","d"]
```

Flattening lists should be possible on with list comprehension as mentioned in many [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists):

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

but is it possible to flatten the list with a character/string of my choosing?

It could be done with by appending `.` to each list except the last one. But is there something more elegant like `.join`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way I can think of is to extend the `sublist` on the second level of iteration by adding the separator:

```
[j for i in l for j in [*i, '.']][:-1]
# ['a', 'b', '.', 'c', '.', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @Kurtis use this only if you have characters in the lists.

```
mylist = [["a", "b"], ["c"], ["d"]]

print(list(".".join(map("".join, mylist))))

# ['a', 'b', '.', 'c', '.', 'd']
```

UPDATE:

There are multiple ways to do this, I'll mention a few.

For a given `mylist`

```
mylist = [["asd", "b"], ["csd"], ["d"]]
```

Method 1: Using `reduce`

```
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(lambda a, b: a+["."]+b, mylist))
```

Method 2:

```
print([item for sublist in mylist for item in sublist+["."]][:-1])
```

Method 3: Same as Method 2

```
flat_list = []
[flat_list.extend(sublist + ["."]) for sublist in mylist][:-1]
print(flat_list)
```

Method 4: If you can afford two separators then split with the other

```
print("~.~".join(map("~".join, mylist)).split("~"))
```

Comment: Note that this solution is only correct if each individual string is a single character as it relies on the implicit splitting of strings into individual characters when the string is used as an iterable. This is not a general solution to the problem. The solution by @yatu is better.